# background color change, timed using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, background

I have this JS Fiddle that I found, and I know to insert it into the background of the whole page I just add the div id to the body tag as shown below.

however can somebody show me actually on a page showing the source code how to lay it out as I can not get it to work in dreamweaver.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/7peJT/6/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(element, curNumber){
curNumber++;

if(curNumber > 4){
    curNumber = 1;
}
console.log(curNumber);
element.addClass('color' + curNumber, 500);
// So previous classes get removed.
element.attr('class', 'color' + curNumber);
setTimeout(function(){changeColor(element, curNumber)}, 1000);  
}

changeColor($('#testElement'), 0);
</script>
```

Thanks guys
:)

Comment: Are you including jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: @DerekS Im not sure what you mean

Comment: Take a look at the frameworks and extensions section on the left. This will show you what additional code is being used in the fiddle.

Comment: @DerekS Im sorry but it didn't show me, it just had Jquery 6.1 ticked, Im not sure what I am meant to be looking for :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
element = $("#testElement");
i = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
            element.removeClass("color"+i);
            console.log(i);
            i++
            if(i == 5) {
            i = 1;
            }
            element.addClass("color"+i);
        }, 1000);
})
</script>
<style>
.color1{
    background: yellow;
}

.color2{
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.color3{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

.color4{
    background: green;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="testElement">Im a test element for testing OMG!!!!?!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: truly an amazing person, you will have a high reputation in no time! Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you include the JQuery framework before you run any JQuery code.

```
<head>
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<other scripts using JQuery syntax go here>
</head>
```

Comment: I have the one above in the head section, and the js in the head section too but still nothing :(

Comment: Do you have any errors in chrome inspector or firebug? (press F12)

Comment: I have these ones ----- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
-----Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:10
-----Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: I am so so grateful for you trying to help me but it made no difference :(

Comment: I have added coding to the original question if it helps :) thank you again

Comment: I will have a look :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I await your answer, people like you make this website a much better place :)